# Make a data-loader (yielding function) buffer its next yield

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, multiprocessing

So far, I only used `Multiprocessing` and `Multi-threading` on `functions` that `return` a result at the end. I know `multiprocessing.Queue` and `multiprocessing.Queue.get()` but I just don't understand how I could apply this to a data_loader..

I struggle with the following task:

```
def data_loader():
    for _ in range(10**6):
        #calculates for some seconds
        yield result

for data in data_loader():
    train_AI(data)
    #Here an AI is being trained for another some seconds
```

So my question is: Is there any easy way to have my existing `data_loader` calculate (pre-buffer) its next `yield` while the AI is being trained on the GPU?

Or would I have to completely restructure this, with an external iterator that calls an inner smaller data_loader that `returns` a single batch each time it's called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, you can use Python's Queue:

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue
from time import sleep    
FINISHED_LOADING_DATA = 'LAST ONE'  # just make sure it's not something that can be returned by some_function()

def some_function():
    print('getting data')
    sleep(0.5)
    return 'some_result'


def train_AI(x):
    print('training AI')
    sleep(2)


q = Queue()
final_results = []

def data_loader(q):
    for _ in range(10):
        result = some_function()
        q.put(result)
    q.put(FINISHED_LOADING_DATA)


def train_if_data_available():
    while True:
        data = q.get()
        if data == FINISHED_LOADING_DATA:
            return 'DONE'
        train_AI(data)


t = Process(target=data_loader, args=(q,))
t.daemon = True
t.start()

train_if_data_available()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will use your exact suggestion! And if I still want the generator property, then can I replace "return done" with "break" and "train AI(data)" with "yield"?

Comment: Check it out and let us know, haha

Comment: I will do so! :) Oh and another question: I noticed you define "final_results = []" but don't use it any more. Can I just ignore that line or is there something you forgot?

Comment: You can ignore it, I was playing around and forgot to delete it :)

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! By the way I already tried and I was able to make a generator with my mentioned changes! Works perfectly!

Comment: glad to hear that :D